# Removing the last blank line within a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string which contains many rows of data which has been converted from a datatable. The last row of my string has nothing within it, no spaces or anything. How can I get rid of this row? I have tried regex, but cant seem to get anything that does the job. I am writing in VB.

Code as it stands:

```
Dim objSW As StreamWriter
Dim merRersult As String
Dim objSW As StreamWriter

Dim objFS As New FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew)
objFS.Close()
objSW = New StreamWriter(path, True)
merRersult = Delta.Utilities.Convert.DataTableToCSV(dt, True, sep)

'Write out mer file
 Dim merResultNoLines As String
 merResultNoLines = Regex.Replace(merRersult, "^\r?\n?$", "")


 objSW.WriteLine(merRersult)
 objSW.Close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And C# or VB.NET should be in **tags** - not the title...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try to use [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx#Y0) method in the following way:

```
merResultNoLines = merRersult.TrimEnd('\n', '\r')
```

Comment: I had to use .TrimEnd(vbCrLf, vbCr, vbLf) to get it to work properly just now, but it works perfectly!